# Split the content in paragraph when encountered first letter "x"?

Tags: javascript

Example: `Alex is my name!`

I wan't to assign in variable for the first word that end with letter "x".

What jquery code to  use? your help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is a problem for which jQuery is not a relevant tool.

Comment: The title and the question in the post do not exactly match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regular expression will match a word ending with "x":

```
var firstX = /\b\w*x/;
```

If you run that on some text, the result will contain the word:

```
var match = firstX.exec(someText);
var word = match ? match[0] : null;
```

If you want that word, and then the rest of the string following it:

```
var firstX = /\b(\w*x)\b(.*)$/;
var match = firstX.exec(someText);
var word = match ? match[1] : null;
var theRest = match ? match[2] : null;
```

Comment: You could also add a default word if none is found: `var firstX = (someText.match(/\b\w*x\b/) || ['word'])[0]`

Comment: Thanks Pointy, you are great. How about the rest of the string I want to store in another variable? Just like my first string: Alex is my name!  var firstX = /\b\w*x/; is equal to "Alex" then what if I also store in another variable for the remaining string "is my name"? I know you this is basic for you. And one thing, I tried your first code for multiple paragraph, it only read the first paragraph. Please help.

Comment: @Cha I will update the answer. Basically you can get it from a modified version of that regular expression.

Comment: You did a great answer. I salute you.

Comment: @Cha well detecting paragraph breaks is sort-of a different problem. How you do that depends on your markup. For example, if your paragraphs are all `<p>` tags, you could go through and process each `<p>` separately.

Comment: <html> 
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="content">Alex is my name</p>
<p class="content">Hex value for white is #fff</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('p.content').each(function() {
var content = $('p.content').html();
var X = /\b\w*./;
var Y = /\b(\w*.)\b(.*)$/;
var getX = X.exec(content);
var getY = Y.exec(content);
var theRest = getY ? getY[2]:null;
alert(getX)
alert(theRest)
});
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I have my sample code above. If I use single paragraph, it works fine but when I write multiple paragraph then the rest of paragraph will not display. I'm not yet good in jquery and maybe your expertise can fix my problem. Thanks in advance, you are my master.

Comment: @Cha maybe you should start a new question on the subject of breaking up text into paragraphs. It's hard to read code posted into a comment :-)

Comment: I tried to post new question but unable to post of some errors. Anyway thanks very much. you reply my first post with a very relevant answer.

Comment: @Pointy have a nice day sir. here is the link of my separate posted question continuation to your impressive answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063591/please-help-jquery-execute-only-for-the-first-paragraph