# Please help jQuery execute only for the first paragraph

Tags: jquery

Some jquery code below works fine just like adding element inside the paragraph.
My problem is it's only displaying the first paragraph and repeated number of times of how many number of paragraph in the body. Just check my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('p.content').each(function() {
var content = $(this).html();    
var beforeContent = "<em>";
var afterContent = "</em>";
$(this).html(beforeContent+content+afterContent)
});
})
</script>
<p class="content">Hex value of white is #FFFFFF;</p>
<p class="content">Hex value of black is #000000;</p>
<p class="content">Hex value of blue is #0000FF;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should not have duplicate ID's. use classes if you want to have duplicates.

Comment: and that is your problem. it's only seeing the first #content.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
var content = $('p#content').html();
$('p#content').html(getX+beforeContent+theRest+afterContent)
<p id="content">Hex value of white is #FFFFFF;</p>
<p id="content">Hex value of black is #000000;</p>
<p id="content">Hex value of blue is #0000FF;</p>
```

to

```
 <p class="content">Hex value of white is #FFFFFF;</p>
<p class="content">Hex value of black is #000000;</p>
<p class="content">Hex value of blue is #0000FF;</p>
var content = $('.content').html();
$('.content').html(getX+beforeContent+theRest+afterContent)
```

Comment: thanks for your correction Sir. I tried to edit using your updated code but the inserting of element <em> not working. Can you help this?

Answer (score 0):

`ID` should be unique. You can't use same `ID` on another elements. Instead use `class`

If you need only first element to get update then use [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

For Eg:

```
$('p#content').first().html(getX+beforeContent+theRest+afterContent)
```

Here is the full code, (change `id` to `class`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var content = $('p.content').html();
  var X = /\b\w*x/; 
  var Y = /\b(\w*x)\b(.*)$/; 
  var getX = X.exec(content); 
  var getY = Y.exec(content); 
  var theFirst = getY ? getY[1]:null; 
  var theRest = getY ? getY[2]:null; 
  var beforeContent = "<em>";
  var afterContent = "</em>";
  $('p.content').first().html(getX+beforeContent+theRest+afterContent)
})
</script>
  <p class="content">Hex value of white is #FFFFFF;</p>
  <p class="content">Hex value of black is #000000;</p>
  <p class="content">Hex value of blue is #0000FF;</p>
</body>
</html>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qpBaS/

Comment: thanks for your correction Sir. I tried to edit using your updated code but the inserting of element <em> not working. Can you help this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the p-tags if you want to do all of them

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('p.content').each(function() {
            var content = $(this).html();
            var X = /\b\w*x/; 
            var Y = /\b(\w*x)\b(.*)$/; 
            var getX = X.exec(content); 
            var getY = Y.exec(content); 
            var theFirst = getY ? getY[1]:null; 
            var theRest = getY ? getY[2]:null; 
            var beforeContent = "<em>";
            var afterContent = "</em>";
            $(this).html(getX+beforeContent+theRest+afterContent)
        });
    })
</script>
```

Then change the `id` to `class`

```
<p class="content">Hex value of white is #FFFFFF;</p>
<p class="content">Hex value of black is #000000;</p>
<p class="content">Hex value of blue is #0000FF;</p>
```

Comment: thanks for your correction Sir. I tried to edit using your updated code but the inserting of element <em> not working. Can you help this?

Comment: I'm not sure why the `<em>` isn't working, but if you change it out for `<i>` it seems to work [check example](http://jsfiddle.net/54XB2/71/)